# How to debug a MIPS code? Affectation issues

Tags: debugging, mips

I am trying to replicate this Java function in MIPS:

```
static int gmul(int a, int b) {
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if ( (b & 1) == 1) p = p ^ a;
            a = a << 1;
            if ( a > 255 ) a = a ^ 283;     
            b = b >> 1;
        }
    return p ;
}
```

I have this MIPS code:

```
.data
    demanda:
        .asciiz "Enter a first number"

    demandb:
        .asciiz "Enter a second number"
  
.text
main: 
    la $a0, demanda
    li $v0, 4               
    syscall
    li $v0, 5               
    syscall 
    move $t2, $v0           
    
    la $a1, demandb                       
    li $v0, 4               
    syscall
    li $v0, 5               
    syscall 
    move $a1, $v0           
    
    move $a0, $t2
    
    li $v0, 0               # this is p in the java version
    li $t0, 0       
    
    jal for         

    li $v0, 1               # Print p
    syscall     
                                    
    li $v0, 10              
    syscall

    
for:
        bge $t0,8,finfor    # if i>=8
        addi $t0, $t0, 1    # Incrementation
        andi $t2, $a1,1     # Preliminary condition calculation: (b & 1) == 1 in Java
        beq $t2,0, bEven    # if ( (b & 1) == 1) in java
        xor $v0, $a0, $v0   # Execution p = p ^ a in Java
bEven:  
        sll $a0, $a0, 1     # Execution a = a << 1 in java
        blt $a0,256, aSmall # if ( a > 255 )
        xori $a0, $a0, 283  # Execution a = a ^ 283 in Java
aSmall: 
        srl $a1, $a1, 1     # Execution b = b >> 1 in java
        j for  
finfor:
        jr $ra
```

I think the formulas are OK, as the program runs, but it does not returns p as expected. It seems that it rather return a (which is in $a0), which I don't understand as I have put p in $v0 and try to print this one.
But it is not the first time I am struggling with registers and affectations in MIPS.

Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I think the formulas are OK, as the program runs"_ That the code assembles and runs does not mean that it is correct, as you made evident with  _"but it does not returns p as expected"_. Use the simulator's single-stepping functionality to cross-check the result of each step of the calculation against the result you expect to have at that point.

Comment: Very good suggestion, indeed, tks

Comment: Found it, thanks @Michael

Comment: @kAmJi consider posting a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you solved the problem. This helps future visitors who have the same problem as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The trick in MIPS is that the print out command `li $v0, 1` can override the value that you may want to print in $v0, that was my mistake. The work around is to store the data in another register first:

```
move $a2, $v0       
...
move $a0 $a2    
li $v0, 1       
syscall
```

Or preferably, not using $v0 for the variable you need to handle.
And the step by single-step functionality really helps to find out mistakes.